# Sqlite database doesn't update the table with the new value taken?

Tags: python, sqlite

My sqlite database is not updating, the code below validates if the currentusername exists, if it does it redirects to the updateusername function which takes 2 variables, currentusername which is the old value which is in the table and newusername is the new value that should replace the old one. However, it doesn't update the old value in the database.

```
    def ChangeUsername(self):
        loadUi("ChangeUsername.ui",self)

        self.SaveChangesButton.setCheckable(True)

        self.SaveChangesButton.clicked.connect(self.CheckUsername)
        self.SaveChangesButton.clicked.connect(self.UpdateUserna
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters in the tuple must be in the exact same order as in the sql statement:

```
c.execute('UPDATE Account SET username = ? WHERE username = ?',(self.newusername,self.currentusername,))
```